# pick enough items from several locations without doing rbar

Tags: sql, t-sql, rbar

I have a warehouse, where each itemnumber can be in several locations.
I have a preferred order where to pick from.

```
ITEM   LOC   IN_STOCK
item_1 loc_1 3
item_1 loc_2 3
item_1 loc_3 2
item_2 loc_1 4
```

The preferred order is a function of the location name, for the sake of simplicity, lets just say it is `order by loc asc`

I have an order

```
item_1 4
item 2 2
```

I want a picklist to enter into a third table.

```
item_1 loc_1 3
item_1 loc_2 1
item_2 loc_1 2
```

If I just make a join, I get three rows of item_1

I'd like to do it in a single sql-statement, not a RBAR, Row By Agonizing Row loop.

I'm using Mssql 2008

Comment: Where you are specifying the preferred order of picking items?

Comment: Isnt this something you would like to do with a Stored Procedure ?? I mean check the stock 1st and then add it to the third table.

Comment: M.Ali Like first taking 4 item_1 from loc_1, then the trigger sees that there are -1 in stock, adding 1, and search for the remaining 1 in another location? RBAR seems more manageable :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please try using CTE:

```
;with T as(
  select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by item order by in_stock, LOC desc) RNum
  From warehouse)
select 
    x.Item,
    x.Loc,
    (case when SM-ItemNum<=in_stock then SM-ItemNum else in_stock end) as in_stock
From(
    select *,(select SUM(b.In_stock) from T b where b.item=a.item and b.RNum<=a.RNum) SM
    from T a
)x inner join orders c on x.item=c.item
where SM-ItemNum>0
```

Check solution here [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8522c/2)

Comment: @PeterRing Please mention the reason.

Comment: Excusse me i was a little tired yesterday. Try it with: create table Orders(ITEM nvarchar(100), ItemNum int);
insert into Orders values
('item_1',7),
('item_2',2); And you will see the problem.

Comment: I also found it non-working. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43ce7/1
Reduced ('item_1','loc_1',1), and now only get 2 item_1 even when 4 is ordered.

Not sure how it is supposed to work, and why it isn't