# Query For Generating Item Pick List From Multiple Locations

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm designing a warehouse management system esque service. Hoping to get some input here on the deisgn for the pick list.

In essence I have the following Postgres tables:

Item Locations Table

```
ITEM    LOCATION QUANTITY
item_1  A1       1
item_2  A1       9
item_1  A2       1
item_1  B1       2
```

Orders Table

```
ORDER  ITEM     QUANTITY
1      item_1   3
1      item_2   1
```

What I expect to get in the end:
Pick List

```
ITEM     LOCATION  QUANTITY
item_1   A1        1
item_2   A1        1
item_1   A2        1
item_1   B1        1
```

The resulting item locations table should also then reflect the reduced inventory that was just picked.

My first question is can I do this in Postgres or should I do this in code? Code (node.js app) feels easier to me as I just iterate over all returned rows but I want this to be quick so my initial thought went to SQL and set based operations.

I found this really old post from 10 years ago: [pick enough items from several locations without doing rbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702614/pick-enough-items-from-several-locations-without-doing-rbar) and I was able to get the query in the answer to execute but the solution has an issue when joining table T with it self. I think it is because it doesn't account for the qty "picked" in the previous rows.

Comment: what is the logic of your QUANTITY column ?

Comment: This is going to be dominated by the practicalities of running a warehouse which aren't considered here.  Are the orders all-or-none or can you do partial fills? What if an item is found to be missing or damaged when you go to pick it? If you have multiple pick lists being generated at the same time, what do you do when they all can't be fulfilled?  When executing a pick list stalls out someplace, how long do you wait until declaring it abandoned and releasing the items to be picked for other orders?

Comment: @jjanes yep, those are all good questions and are part of my design. I'm hoping to at least get this very basic best case example working then I can modify it to account for all the other cases that happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to generate the pick list and update each item's location's quantity in a single SQL query. The following demonstrates one approach.

Setup the demonstration tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS items_locations cascade;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS items cascade;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS locations cascade;

CREATE TABLE locations (
  id INTEGER generated always AS identity PRIMARY key,
  name TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE items (
  id INTEGER generated always AS identity PRIMARY key,
  name TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE items_locations (
  item_id INTEGER REFERENCES items (id),
  location_id INTEGER REFERENCES locations (id),
  quantity INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO
  locations (name)
VALUES
  ('A1'),
  ('A2'),
  ('B1');

INSERT INTO
  items (name)
VALUES
  ('item_1'),
  ('item_2');

INSERT INTO
  items_locations (item_id, location_id, quantity)
VALUES
  (1, 1, 1),
  (2, 1, 9),
  (1, 2, 1),
  (1, 3, 2);
```

The following query creates the pick list and updates `items_locations`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  orders (order_id, item_id, quantity) AS (
    VALUES
      (1, 1, 3),
      (1, 2, 1)
  ),
  picks AS (
    SELECT
      t1.*
    FROM
      (
        SELECT DISTINCT
          ON (o.item_id) il.item_id,
          il.location_id,
          LEAST(o.quantity, il.quantity) AS quantity,
          o.quantity - LEAST(o.quantity, il.quantity) AS required_quantity
        FROM
          orders o
          JOIN items_locations il ON o.item_id = il.item_id
        WHERE
          o.quantity > 0
          AND il.quantity > 0
        ORDER BY
          o.item_id,
          il.location_id
      ) t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      t2.*
    FROM
      (
        SELECT DISTINCT
          ON (picks.item_id) picks.item_id,
          il.location_id,
          LEAST(picks.required_quantity, il.quantity) AS quantity,
          picks.required_quantity - LEAST(picks.required_quantity, il.quantity) AS required_quantity
        FROM
          picks
          JOIN items_locations il ON picks.item_id = il.item_id
        WHERE
          picks.required_quantity > 0
          AND il.quantity > 0
          AND il.location_id > picks.location_id
        ORDER BY
          picks.item_id,
          il.location_id
      ) t2
  ),
  update_quantities AS (
    UPDATE items_locations il
    SET
      quantity = il.quantity - picks.quantity
    FROM
      picks
    WHERE
      il.item_id = picks.item_id
      AND il.location_id = picks.location_id
  )
SELECT
  i.name AS item,
  l.name AS location,
  picks.quantity,
  MIN(picks.required_quantity) OVER (
    PARTITION BY
      picks.item_id
  ) = 0 AS has_sufficient_quantity
FROM
  picks
  JOIN items i ON picks.item_id = i.id
  JOIN locations l ON picks.location_id = l.id
ORDER BY
  location_id,
  item_id;
```

| item | location | quantity | has_sufficient_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item_1 | A1 | 1 | true |
| item_2 | A1 | 1 | true |
| item_1 | A2 | 1 | true |
| item_1 | B1 | 1 | true |

The first CTE, `orders`, establishes the quantity desired for each item. The recursive CTE, `picks`, finds the first location for each item and then iterates over `items_locations` until the required quantity has been satisfied or there are no more locations with available quantity. The subqueries, `t1` and `t2`, are there to work around the error `ORDER BY in a recursive query is not implemented`. The next CTE, `update_quantities`, reduces each item's location's quantity by the number of items picked. The main query returns the pick list. The column, `has_sufficient_quantity`, is `true` when there was sufficient quantity available across locations for the item.

The query only works if each item occurs only once in `orders`; however, it can be enhanced to handle multiple orders with repeated occurrences of each item.

The following query demonstrates that the quantities in `items_locations` have been updated:

```
SELECT
  i.name as item,
  l.name as location,
  il.quantity
FROM
  items_locations il
  join items i on il.item_id = i.id
  join locations l on il.location_id = l.id
ORDER BY
  location_id,
  item_id;
```

| item | location | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item_1 | A1 | 0 |
| item_2 | A1 | 8 |
| item_1 | A2 | 0 |
| item_1 | B1 | 1 |

Comment: This is awesome work! I'll give it a try later tonight!